Should one pay more than one fifth (20%) for goods or services from a fellow Jew?
On a recent shiur, a Rov mentioned that one is supposed to spend up to a fifth (20%) more on goods or services provided by a fellow Jew. So for example, if you're in a Jewish bookstore and they're selling a book that's a couple dollars cheaper on Amazon, it would be preferable to purchase it from the Jewish bookstore, even for more than it's listed on Amazon, as long as it's not over 20% more expensive.
Is there a source for this minhag? Is it a halacha?
This was specifically referring to a non-mitzva related item. Just general business transactions.

The question title says more than one fifth but the body says up to one fifth. Which are you asking about?

Can the difference be counted as tzedaka?

I wonder! I guess we need an actual source for this to know.

Rav Moshe Zvi Neria wrote that one must buy produce from Jews, even if it costs up to a third more.  His teacher Rav Kook concurred but rejected the one-third limit, saying there is no limit.  [Likutei HaRe’iyah, Kfar Haroeh, 1991, pp. 279-280.]   The Rema said one must support Jewish businesses even if their price is higher.[Teshuvot HaRema 10]  However, the Chafetz Chayyim ruled that there is no obligation, but it is preferable to deal with Jewish businesses, even if the cost is slightly higher. [Ahavat Chesed 5:6-7]  I think the halacha of the matter is not completely settled.

Interesting! So no mention of a fifth more!?

@TheThinkingYid -- Not in my sources.

very interesting! i wonder where it came from.
